# Grabbing values from Expression.Blend.SampleData

Tags: c#, silverlight, expression-blend

I am trying to figure out how to grab a value from Expression.Blend.SampleData.  If my id is equal to a drop down for example, I can grab it by doing this:

```
((Expression.Blend.SampleData.MyDatabase.something)(MyDropDown.SelectedItem)).description;
```

I need some way to place my own value where (MyDropDown.SelectedItem) is.  Visual studio wants me to convert it a "Expression.Blend.SampleData.MyDatabase.something" format.  I have tried a few ways to do this but I have been unsuccessful.

Any Ideas?

**EDIT**

I am starting to think there is no way in Silverlight to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most answers I come up with, this was simple:

```
((Expression.Blend.SampleData.MyDatabase.MyMainCollection)(((object[])(Application.Current.Resources.Values))[0])).MyCollection[1].Description
```

The MyColleciton[1] will grab the item with an id value of 1.